# networkx - python - distance between nodes nx.draw_graphviz()

Tags: python, graphviz, networkx

I'm using networkx to make some graphs. I like the output of the `fdp` layout with [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).
However, I can't seem to get the nodes to space apart far enough to vizualize.

I've tried using `scale`, `K` and `nodesep` in the `nx.draw()` command, however a lot of the nodes are still jumbled and can't be seen because of overlap. I decreased the node size from 300 (default) to 200, still not too good. Any smaller and the colors I've added are not easily recognizable.

There are approx. 2400 nodes. Does anyone know how to space nodes with `nx.draw_graphviz(g, prog="fdp")`? Ideally I would like to order the nodes from largest cluster to smallest in a vertical fashion, but can't seem to find a layout.

I tried using `prog="dot"` and using `rankdir="TB"`, but the nodes are still printed left to right in a jumbled order and are very hard to make out. I either need to increase the spacing of the nodes, or make the image much larger, and I've also tried playing around with the parameters to [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) and the image is the same size every time. All thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Just in case you don't get an answer from SO, try asking the developers directly. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/networkx-discuss

Comment: Could you include a few sample codes / images of the output. Or incase the image is too big include a link to the same.

Comment: the code and images are similar to a question i previously asked..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662006/python-networkx-graph-different-colored-nodes-using-two-lists/24664660?noredirect=1#comment38263595_24664660