# python - plot adjacency matrix with colored nodes according to node class

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

**I want to plot an adjacency matrix where the dots are colored accordind to the nodes class.**

if exist edge between x and y nodes:

- if both of the nodes belong to class 0 => color red
- if both of thenodes belong to class 1 => color blue
- if both of the nodes belong to class 2 => color green
- else => color grey

I have an adjacency matrix from networkx (as nx)
lets say:

```
matrix = np.array([[1 0 0 0 0],[1 0 1 0 0],[1 1 0 1 0],[1 0 0 0 1],[1 0 1 0 0]])
```

I also have an attribute called 'network_num' for each node classifing it to 0 or 1 or 2.

- node 0 -> 0
- node 1 -> 0
- node 2 -> 1
- node 3 -> 1
- node 4 -> 2

  network_num = {0:0,1:0,2:1,3:1,4:2}

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "plot an adjacency matrix"?  Do you want to draw the graph with nodes having those colors?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662006/python-networkx-graph-different-colored-nodes-using-two-lists may answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that with "plot an adjacency matrix" you mean just that, ploting an numpy matrix, and that by "dots" you mean elements in the matrix.

In the code below I use your `matrix` and `network_num` to create my `drawn_matrix` (which will be ploted).
After I check that an edge exists, I assign `drawn_matrix` 0.25 for your "red" case, 0.5 for your "blue" case and 1.0 for your "green" case (more about these numbers below).
Note that I marked no edges (0 in the `matrix`) as gray.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

# Graph data
network_num = {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2}
matrix = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                   [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                   [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]])

drawn_matrix = np.zeros((5, 5))

# Iterate 5x5 matrix
for row in range(5):
    for col in range(5):
        # check if edge exists
        if matrix[row][col] == 1:
            # red
            if network_num[row] == 0 and network_num[col] == 0:
                drawn_matrix[row][col] = 0.25
            # blue
            elif network_num[row] == 1 and network_num[col] == 1:
                drawn_matrix[row][col] = 0.5
            # green
            elif network_num[row] == 2 and network_num[col] == 2:
                drawn_matrix[row][col] = 1.0
            # gray
            else:
                drawn_matrix[row][col] = 0.0
        else:
            drawn_matrix[row][col] = 0.0  # no edge is marked as gray

print("Matrix with color info:")
print(drawn_matrix)
```

Here's the output (the matrix which I will plot). Note that based on your `matrix` and `network_num` there will be no green in the plot.

```
Matrix with color info:
[[ 0.25  0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.25  0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.5   0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  ]]
```

Now the acctual plot. Here I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16836182/6696049) anwser very helpful.
In the code I define a custom colormap with the following colors: gray, red, blue and green. Note that the numerical values in `rvb` match the values in the code I posted earlier.

```
def make_colormap(seq):
    """Return a LinearSegmentedColormap
    seq: a sequence of floats and RGB-tuples. The floats should be increasing
    and in the interval (0,1).
    """
    seq = [(None,) * 3, 0.0] + list(seq) + [1.0, (None,) * 3]
    cdict = {'red': [], 'green': [], 'blue': []}
    for i, item in enumerate(seq):
        if isinstance(item, float):
            r1, g1, b1 = seq[i - 1]
            r2, g2, b2 = seq[i + 1]
            cdict['red'].append([item, r1, r2])
            cdict['green'].append([item, g1, g2])
            cdict['blue'].append([item, b1, b2])
    return mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap('CustomMap', cdict)

c = mcolors.ColorConverter().to_rgb
rvb = make_colormap(
    [c('gray'), c('red'), 0.25, c('red'), c('blue'), 0.5, c('blue'), c('green'), 0.75, c('green')])

plt.matshow(drawn_matrix, vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0, cmap=rvb)
plt.show()
```

The final adjacency matrix:

[image]